# The Maclaurin series and taylors theorem for $\sinh(2x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am currently studying for an exam next week but am struggling to the second part of this question. I have figure out the Maclaurin series for $\sinh(2x)$, however am unsure how to estimate the error. Can anybody help??

(5 i) Calculate the Maclaurin series of the function $f(x) = \sinh(2x)$

Recall that $\sinh$ is defined by $$\sinh{x} = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$

(ii) Use Taylor's theorem and your result from (i) to estimate, as well as possible, the error in approximating $\sinh(2x)$ by $2x + \frac{4}{3}x^3$ on the interval $\big[\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big]$

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Taylor-Lagrange Formula :

$$\forall x \in I, \left|f-T_{n,f,a}(x)\right| \leq M_{n+1}(x) \frac{\left|x-a\right|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Where $T_{n,f,a}$ is the $n$th order MacLaurin serie of $f$ in $a$, and $M_{n+1}$ is a function such that $\forall t\in I, M_{n+1}(t)\geq \left|f^{(n+1)}(t)\right|$

Here, clearly, $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}\sinh(2x)= 16\sinh(2x)$, so $M_4=16\sinh(1)$ should be sufficient (of course, $T_{3,\sinh, 0}(x)=2x+\frac{4}{3}x^3$ is the MacLaurin polynomial you mentionned, the one which you want to approximate the error)